# Displaying Feature Layer Field Values on webpage without Map using ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: html

I am just learning JavaScript for this mini-project.

I am looking to display the field values from a service feature layer on a web page using HTML and JS without loading a map and without any input or action from the user.

**Service Feature Layer:** https://services3.arcgis.com/GVgbJbqm8hXASVYi/arcgis/rest/services/Trailheads/FeatureServer/0

**FieldID** = TRL_NAME

What I've been working with so far is below from reading through tutorials and forums, but I can't get it working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="table-responsive">
 <h1> Trails! </h1>
 <br />
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="data_str">
 <tr>
 <th>Trail Name</th>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $.getJSON(
 'https://services3.arcgis.com/GVgbJbqm8hXASVYi/arcgis/rest/services/Trailheads/FeatureServer/0/f=getJSON',
 function(data) {
 var data_str = '';
 console.info(data.features);
 $.each(data.features, function(key, value) {

 data_str += '<td>' + value.TRL_NAME + '</td>';
 data_str += '<tr>';
 });
 $('#data_str').append(data_str);
 });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is with the query string you're sending to the server.

If you scroll down on the [Feature Layer's endpoint](https://services3.arcgis.com/GVgbJbqm8hXASVYi/arcgis/rest/services/Trailheads/FeatureServer/0) you'll see a [Query](https://services3.arcgis.com/GVgbJbqm8hXASVYi/arcgis/rest/services/Trailheads/FeatureServer/0/query) link, which is the endpoint for requesting data.

Set the `where` clause to `1=1` if you want to return all records, or use a SQL query such as `TRL_NAME like 'M%'` to find all records starting with "M":

[image]

Set the `outFields` parameter to `*` to return all fields, or use a comma-delimited list of the desired fields.

Change the `Format` option to `json` to return the results in JSON format, and you'll have the correct syntax for the query:

https://services3.arcgis.com/GVgbJbqm8hXASVYi/arcgis/rest/services/Trailheads/FeatureServer/0/query?where=TRL_NAME+like+%27%25%27&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&f=json

The second problem is that you need to look at the `attributes` parameter of the `value` object, in order to get the name of the trail:

```
$.each(data.features, function(key, value) {
     console.log(value.attributes.TRL_NAME)
```

I put together a rough demo at https://jsfiddle.net/slead/dsxf53ey/7/ to demonstrate some of these changes. Open the Console option and see that it's found Medea Creek trail:

[image]

It still doesn't add the results to your table, but you could look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery for some pointers. I hope this helps get you started.